# How to adjust P values for several Post Hoc tests

Tags: anova, adjustment

I have several continuous dependent variables x1,x2,x3, and one categorical independent variable x4 with 4 levels, I want to apply ANOVA for each of these dependent variables one by one and then do the post hoc comparison test for each test. Forexample, After applying ANOVA for X2 and X4, I need to do the post hoc test. As I have three different ANOVA/Post Hoc tests, how I can adjust the P-values?

1. Do I need to first adjust the p-values-for each of the post hoc tests by using Bonferroni and then apply false discovery rate to adjust all p-values *as I have three independent variables*?

Comment: Start a new Bonferroni computation for each one-factor ANOVA with four levels. Thus if you do _ad hoc_ tests between all ${4\choose2}=6$ pairs of levels, then rejecting at level $0.05/6= 0.0083$ will ensure that the 'family' rate is $\le$ 0.05. // However, if levels A-D ordered by means turns out to be $A > D > B > C,$ you may not have to do 6 tests to discern the pattern of significant differences. Maybe signif pattern $A \approx D >  B \approx C$ could be established with as few as three _ad hoc_ tests. // You don't need to test differences for signif if they are too small to be important .

Comment: As @BruceET alluded, since the $p$-value is the probability of getting a result in general that is more impressive than a specific result, we don't in general have adjustments for $p$-values but rather give a new reference $\alpha$.  But this begs the question of whether we should still be doing significance testing in [this day and age](https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108).  I think not.

Comment: @BruceET, thanks so much for the reply. But in general, can we apply two different adjustment methods? Forexample, If all ANOVA tests are significant, I would have 6*3 (3 variables and 4 levels) comparisons, so  should I apply FDR to adjust them all together or first I should adjust every 6 comparisons by Bonferroni  and then apply FDR (as I have 3 variables/three ANOVA tests/three post hoc tests?)

Comment: The former: As I said in my first comment: "Start a new Bonferroni computation for each one-factor ANOVA with four levels. "